# Show CSS elements on page before content is added

Tags: javascript, css, frontend

Nowadays i see a lot of websites that display all their (empty) elements on the page on load even when the actual content is not loaded yet.

What kind of technique is used for this?

(Example site: https://www.decidee.nl/vergelijk/Rotterdam/?lat=51.9244201&lon=4.4777326&ft=cremation&pkg=c_sober&address=Rotterdam&page=1&props=&awards=&sort=distance&dir=asc)

Comment: There is no such thing as a CSS element.

Comment: All that site is doing is displaying an animation while the data loads

Comment: everything you need to answer your question is available on the page you have linked to _ Simply 'right click' anywhere on your browser screen & 'view source' _ then begin your research

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about something like this: https://cloudcannon.com/deconstructions/2014/11/15/facebook-content-placeholder-deconstruction.html

It is basically done by showing "fake" elements until the real elements are loaded. They then, get replaced.